# Is every invariant subspace also a generalized eigenspace?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, invariant-subspace, generalized-eigenvector

Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional complex vector space and let $U$ be a subspace of $V$ invariant under the linear operator $T$:

$$\forall u\in U: Tu \in U.$$

Must $U$ also be the subspace associated with a generalized eigenvector of $T$ (which I call a “generalized eigenspace” in the post title)? I.e., must we have:

$$\exists \lambda:(T-\lambda I)^{\dim V} u=0\; ?$$

---

I always refer to Sheldon Axler’s “Linear Algebra Done Right” for questions like this, but from what I can tell his theorems don’t answer this. The *converse* is true, which is the content of his Theorem 8.23 (in Ed. 2), but I’m not sure about the other direction.

For context, I’m trying to decide whether $3\times 3$ matrices of the form

$$\pmatrix{1&a&b\\0&1&c\\0&0&1}$$

can have any 2-dimensional invariant subspaces. It is quick to show that its only eigenspace is the one spanned by $(1,0,0)$ and that its only generalized eigenspace is all of $\mathbb R^3$ with eigenvalue $1$. But does this imply that 2-dimensional invariant subspaces can’t exist? It seems this would only necessarily follow if the answer to this post’s question is “yes.” Other opinions welcome.

Comment: Re: Answer that was retracted. What was wrong with it?

Comment: No. Direct sums of generalized eigenspaces with different eigenvalues are also invariant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The subspace of $\mathbb R^3$ spanned by $(1,0,0)$ and $(0,1,0)$ is $A$-invariant. And this shows that an invariant subspace doesn't have to be a generalized eigenspace.

Comment: As the other answer (now retracted) pointed out, this 2D subspace is in fact equal to $\text{null}(T-1\cdot I)^2$. I suppose I should have asked if all invariant subspaces must be of this form.

Comment: Accepting this answer and posting a follow-up here:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3482218/is-every-invariant-subspace-equal-to-some-textnullt-lambda-in