# Is every invariant subspace equal to some $\text{null}(T-\lambda I)^n$?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, invariant-subspace, generalized-eigenvector

This is a natural follow-up to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3482112/is-every-invariant-subspace-also-a-generalized-eigenspace/3482114#3482114) question.

Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional complex vector space and let $U$ be a subspace of $V$ invariant under the linear operator $T$:

$$\forall u\in U: Tu \in U.$$

Assume further that $U$ is not the subspace of an eigenspace of $V$.

Must there exist $\lambda\in\mathbb C,n\in\{1,\dots,\dim V\}$ such that
$$U=\text{null}\,(T-\lambda I)^n \; ?$$

---

The linked question is similar except for requiring $n=\dim V$, and the answer is "no" with a counter-example given. But the counterexample has $\dim V=3$ and still satisfies the above condition for $n=2$. Moreover, there is some reason to suspect this might be true because of the role played by subspaces of this form in the Jordan decomposition.

Comment: Consider the identity operator.

Comment: Just edited the question to rule out subspaces of eigenspaces. Hopefully the question is now nontrivial.

Comment: The same counterexample serves for both of your questions: consider the sum of eigenspaces corresponding to distinct eigenvalues.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.

For one thing, $V$ is always $T$-invariant, and unless $T$ has only one eigenvalue, will not be equal to a generalized eigenspace.

For another example, consider $T\colon\mathbb{C}^3\to\mathbb{C}^3$ given by $T(x,y,z) = (x,2y,z)$. Then $U=\{(x,y,0)\in\mathbb{C}^3\mid x,y\in\mathbb{C}\}$ is $T$-invariant, but is not a generalized eigenspace, or even generated by a union of generalized eigenspaces, because you would need $\lambda=1$ to get the vectors $(x,0,0)$, but that would force you to include the vectors $(0,0,z)$ which are not contained in $U$.

Moreover, you can have a subspace spanned by eigenvectors corresponding to distinct eigenvalues, or by suitably chosen portions of generalized eigenspaces corresponding to distinct eigenvalues, and have an invariant subspace that cannot be expressed as a single generalized eigenspace; and if you don't include *all* the the generalized eigenspace, you will not be able to express them in terms of generalized eigenspaces either.

Now, for a finite dimensional complex vector space, you *can* show that any invariant subspace has a basis of generalized eigenvectors; but that is simply because you can find a Jordan canonical form for the restriction of $T$; the generalized eigenvectors for $T|_U$, when $U$ is $T$-invariant, are also generalized eigenvectors of $T$. So in a sense you can "come down" to some generalized eigenvectors fo $T$, but you won't get **just** a generalized eigenspace.

Comment: Alas, again my question was answered, only to make me realize I was not asking the question I thought I was. I think what I really mean to ask is, if $T$ only has one eigenvalue and a single one-dimensional eigenspace, must all invariant subspaces of $T$ be of the form null$(T-\lambda I)^n$?

Comment: @WillG: if $T$ is over a complex numbers, $T$ has a unique eigenvalue, and the eigenspace is dimension $1$, then its characteristic polynomial is $(\lambda - t)^n$ and its minimal polynomial is $(t-\lambda)^n$, where $n$ is the dimension of $V$. If $U$ is $T$-invariant of dimension $k$, then its characteristic polynomial will necessarily be $(\lambda - t)^k$ and the minimal will be $(t-\lambda)^k$, and in particular every element of $U$ lies in $N(T-\lambda I)^k$; one can show that $N((T-\lambda I)^i)$ has dimension $i$ in this situation, so $U$ *is* that nullspace. In that special case, “yes”

Comment: Why must the degree of the minimal polynomial be equal to the dimension of $V$ in this case? It must have something to do with the eigenspace being dimension 1, but I'm still not seeing it.

Comment: @WillG: The degree of the minimal polynomial in this case is the size of the (unique) Jordan block of the Jordan canonical form for $T$.

Comment: Ah, ok. I learned linear algebra from Axler's book, which unfortunately never spells out the connection between Jordan form and the minimal polynomial, but now I found some sources on it. Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: @WillG: The highest power of $(t-\lambda)$ that divides the minimal polynomial is the size of the largest Jordan block associated to $\lambda$ in the JCF for $T$. The minimal polynomial equals the characteristic polynomial if and only if there is only one block for each eigenvalue (assuming the characteristic polynomial splits, of course).